# How to add a row and change cell value in DataGridView from a different thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, datagridview

I am using a `DataGridView` table in my windows form.
I want to add new row and change the cell values of the same row from inside a thread repeatedly.

Now I know how to use `Invoke` function to change text of a control.
For example:

```
public void SetControlText(Control control, string text)
{
  if (this.InvokeRequired)
  {
    this.Invoke(new Action<Control, string>(SetControlText), new object[] { control, text });
  }
  else
  {
    control.Text = text;
  }
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to do this for `DataGridView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does work exactly the same way, e.g.:

```
public void SetCellText(DataGridView control, int x, int y, string text)
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        this.Invoke(() => SetCellText(control, x, y, text));
    }
    else
    {
        control[x, y] = text;
    }
}
```

I only changed the `Invoke` call to use a lambda action - I like it more that way, but your way would also work...

Comment: If i use lambda expression, i'll have to make it delegate otherwise it'll throw an error `Cannot convert lambda expression to System.Delegate`